# Воспроизведение видео на 2-ом экране

Tags: видео

Надо вывести видео на весь экран с ноута на второй монитор№2. Чтобы всех манипуляции при переключении файлов не было видно. Хотелось элементы управления видео оставить на мониторе№1.

Winamp в принципе обладает таким функционалом (classic skin) но видео при воспроизведении притормаживает. The Kmplayer отлично всё воспроизводит но тему с разбитием на окна для него не могу найти, на оф сайте kmp ни хрена скачать нельзя файлы все удалены с хранилищ. Что можно еще придумать?

Comment: винамп притормаживать может из за формата виде, то есть не тянет его ноут... Может перекодировать?

Comment: Спасибо за совет! В конечном итоге так и сделал ))! Но тему все таки под KMP нашел, правда пришлось скачать целый пак из 170 тем))